# VS Code - Paste these recommended settings in your workspace settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently installed VS Code and then a plugin named Vue.js extension pack. It prompts me in [the website](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shekhardtu.vuejspack) to

> Paste these recommended settings in VS Code workspace settings to
>   supercharged your code.

Where should I paste this code? Preferably a folder and file name.

Comment: Related: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Comment: I did, it was far too general and all encompassing for me to figure out what I needed to know. All I want to know is where to place the code in respect to that one plugin.

Comment: Isn't this https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations and the following (note in the image *"place your setting here..."*) what are you looking for?

Comment: I believe that line refers to User settings as opposed to workspace settings. I assume that every plugin has its own settings and unsure how to separate them or where to place them.

Comment: Workspace settings - is just a folder scoped settings.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Or from Command Palette: `Preferences: Open Workspace Settings`

Command that can be assigned to a keybinding: `workbench.action.openWorkspaceSettings`